# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmModuleOptions (?)

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a typeorm.config.ts file and an app.module.ts file.

typeorm.config.ts

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

export const typeORMConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: "mysql",
  database: "abc",
  host: "abc",
  port: 1234,
  username: "root",
  password: "1234",
  logging: true,
  entities: ["dist/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  synchronize: true,
};
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";
import { PostModule } from "./post/post.module";
import { typeORMConfig } from "./configs/typeorm.config";

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(typeORMConfig),
    AuthModule,
    PostModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I run npm run start, the following error appears.

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TypeOrmModuleOptions (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmCoreModule context.
Potential solutions:
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmCoreModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmCoreModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
```

I couldn't find the cause of that error.
what am i doing wrong?
I need help.

Comment: How are you not getting a compilation error from Typescript? `TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync` should only be accepting `TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions` but you're passing it `TypeOrmModuleOptions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is some problem with the way you are initializing `TypeOrmModule`

There are three options `forRoot`, `forFeature` and `forRootAsync`

Looking at the example you have provided, you want to load the configuration asynchronously with `forRootAsync` which expects `TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions` as an argument

In that case, your `TypeOrmModule` binding should look like following

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: DatabaseConfiguration,
      inject: [ConfigService],
   })
```

Where `DatabaseConfiguration` should be an async function that returns the following function

```js
export default (configService: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions => {
  const options: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'mysql',
    host: configService.get('database.host'),
    port: +configService.get<number>('database.port'),
    username: configService.get('database.user'),
    password: configService.get('database.password'),
    database: configService.get('database.name'),
    entities: [/** entities here **/],
    synchronize: false,
  };
  return options;
};
```

And to load database credentials and other variables from the environment variables or other secret managers you should use `ConfigService` from `ConfigModule`

If you want to load database credentials and other details synchronously then you should use `forRoot` which expects `TypeOrmModuleOptions` as an argument as follows

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ \** JSON here **\})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful to resolve this issue.
This kind of error occurred because missing "imports: [ConfigModule],".

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule,ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";


@Module({
    imports:[
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory:async (configService : ConfigService)=>({
                type: 'postgres',
                host: configService.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
                port: parseInt(configService.get('DATABASE_PORT')),
                username: configService.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
                password: configService.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
            }),
           
        }),
        
    ],
})
```